Move semantic: Why does the return statement call the copy constructor, when the parameter is an rvalue reference?
Consider the following code:
class Widget {
public:
    Widget() {
        std::cout << "\nCtor";
    }
    Widget(const Widget& obj) {
        std::cout << "\nCopy ctor";
    }
    Widget(Widget&& obj) noexcept {
        std::cout << "\nMove Ctor";
    }
};

Widget foo(Widget obj) {
    return obj;
}

And the caller side:
foo(std::move(w));

In this case we will have
Ctor
Move Ctor
Move Ctor

Even though we receive obj in foo by value, the move constructor will be called due to the std::move. The second call of the move constructor will be done by the compiler as an optimization (is that correct?)
However, if we will change foo to the
Widget foo(Widget&& obj) {
    return obj;
}

the output will be
Ctor
Copy ctor

So my question is: why is it called copy constructor instead of the move constructor in the return statement, as before? We can only force the move constructor to be called by return std::move(obj)

GCC calls the move constructor in the second snippet if you compile with -std=c++20 or newer.

Also it's a good idea to make your code into a single snippet we can paste and run directly (don't remove headers, don't remove main, etc; see [mcve]).

at least before C++20 only non-static function local variables and value parameters are considered as rvalues in the return statement.  Everything else is treated as an lvalue.

Return a named object of a class from a function (by value ) and implicit move rule?

@OP You can use the following demo as a [mcve]
